# Como clicar em links com Selenium Python

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Tenho essa tag `<a href="!!!!!!">carro</a>` eu uso o seguinte código `do = driver.find_element_by_link_text('carro') do.click()`

Não consigo acessar, retorna o seguinte erro:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == carro`

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode clicar pelo XPath do elemento. Para isso, basta seguir o modelo:

**Pegando o xpath de um elemento:**

Para pegar o xpath, utilizando o **Google Chorme**, basta clicar com o **botão direito no elemento** -> **Inspecionar** -> **Botão direito na parte iluminada** -> **Copy** -> **Copy XPath**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, para clicar, utilize o código abaixo:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[2]').click()
```

Onde `//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[2]` é o XPath do elemento que está na sua área de transferência.